# How do I use HandlerAdapter in the Spring MVC framework to test @ResponseBody controller actions?

Tags: spring, testing, spring-mvc

I'm currently using Spring MVC's `HandlerAdapter` to test the annotations of my Spring controller actions to make sure the path variables, request parameters, session attributes, @Valid, etc. are being written correctly.

I've come across a problem where if a controller action has `@ResponseBody` and doesn't return a `ModelAndView`, I cannot test the response using the `HandlerAdapter`.

I found a question on this site that is related, but the accepted answer given is not satisfactory:

[How to unit test a ResponseBody or ResponseEntity sent by a spring mvc Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394002/how-to-unit-test-a-responsebody-or-responseentity-sent-by-a-spring-mvc-controlle)

How can I test the annotations and the results at the same time? Or do I need to write two tests - one to test the annotations, and another to call the controller method directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `@ResponseBody` then the handler shouldn't return a `ModelAndView`, it should write directly to the Response using a MessageConvert.

One approach would be to intercept the Response and read it instead of reading the returned value.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I am having a bit of difficulty with `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody` using the HandlerAdapter. I'd like to be able to test these annotations, as well as the annotations I can already test with the HandlerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138555/spring-framework-test-restful-web-service-controller-offline-i-e-no-server-n) answer I just found to your very same question I had:

I found that very useful and I'm implementing this solution in my test code.